# Provide a timestamp when a particular row is edited

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I noticed this code from a thread I was reviewing as I needed the same functionality to provide a timestamp when a particular row is edited in a Google Spreadsheet;

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 18 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

It works perfectly I was able to determine how to modify it to place the timestamp in column R which suited my needs but is there a simple way to make it ignore Row 1 which is the column headers?

Comment: I believe the original answer was provided by 
answered Oct 8 '12 at 20:06

OnenOnlyWalter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap an extra conditional around the "stamping" code. Check the **row** value and only execute the stamping part if the row is NOT 1.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 18 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    if (row != 1) {
      var time = new Date();
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
    };
  };
 };
```